# format date to MMMYYYY JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

I would like to format a date to be in the date format of MMMYYYY. For example, if "Tue Jan 26 2021 12:45:59 GMT+0300" is being returned from new Date(), then I would like it to be displayed as "Jan2021".
How can I do that using JS?
Thanks.

Comment: please add code attempts

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in date functions of Javascript and get the desired output. Like below code snippet:

```
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec' ];

let date = new Date();
// For Jan month, getMonth will return 0. 
const currentMonth = date.getMonth();
const dateStr = months[currentMonth] + date.getFullYear();
console.log(dateStr);
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sagarag05/1bsj39ah/7/

Kindly note, the month names are in English. So they are not localised in case if you have those constraints, that is not considered here.

Answer (score 1):

The `toString()` method returns a string representing the specified Date object.

```
let date = new Date().toString().split(" ")
let result = date[1]+date[3]
console.log(result) //Jan2021
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `.toString().slice(start, end)` Methods, so in your example like this:
`.toString().slice(4,11)` then you get `"Jan 26 2021"` or you can use the same methods and add the two substrings together, like `.substring(4,6) + .substring(10,13).`

I hope i could help you :D

Answer (score 0):

Store months into array like this and then, just use the month index.

```
var monthNames = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
  "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
];

var date = new Date()
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)
date = monthNames[date.getMonth()]+""+date.getFullYear()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **toDateString()** and then split the string to take the values that you want.

```
>> date = new Date()

>> date = date.toDateString()

"Tue Jan 26 2021"

>> date.split(" ")[1] + date.split(" ")[3]

"Jan2021"
```